# Abrir vista en una nueva pestaña HTML

Tags: javascript, html, c#, mvc

Estoy tratando de abrir una nueva pestaña siempre y cuando se cumplan ciertas condiciones. Para ello, tengo entendido que se usa `target="_blank"` en el `form` del `html`, el problema con esto es que se abrirán independientemente de si se cumple o no la condición. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solo suceda cuando se cumpla la condición?

Este es mi ActionResult con el que controlo las condiciones:

```
    public ActionResult ChAzul(double? titulo)
    {
        ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
        var suscriptor = cn.cargarDatos(Convert.ToDouble(titulo));
        var caracteres = Convert.ToString(titulo).Length;
        string uname = string.Empty;
        if (Session["uname"] != null)
        {
            uname = Convert.ToString(Session["uname"]);
        }
        var usuario = cn.datosCob(uname);
        if (uname == string.Empty)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else if (usuario[0].conectado == false)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else if (caracteres <= 3 || caracteres > 6)
        {
            ViewBag.Alert = "La cantidad de caracteres no puede ser menor a 4 (cuatro) ni mayor a 6 (seis).";
            return View("Cuotas", usuario);
        }
        else if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, este título no existe.";
            return View("Cuotas", usuario);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("ChAzul", suscriptor);
        }
    }
```

Solo en esta línea `return View("ChAzul", suscriptor);` es cuando se debe abrir la nueva pestaña, ¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Esta es mi vista por si sirve de algo:

```
        <form id="frmCU" method="post" action="@Url.Action("ChAzul", "Home")">
            <label for="titulo">Título: </label>
            <input type="number" id="titulo" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="titulo" maxlength="6" placeholder="Ingrese su título..." required
                   title="Sólo letras y números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 4. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 5"
                   onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" autofocus>
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
            @if (ViewBag.Alert != null)
            {
                <div class="alert">
                    <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
                    <strong>Providus informa: </strong>
                    <p id="textoAlerta">@ViewBag.Alert</p>
                </div>
            }
        </form>
```

Comment: haz probado con esto ?  return RedirectToAction("Action","controller", new {@id=id}); el @id serian tus parametros de suscriptor

Comment: El RedirectToAction no abre nuevas pestañas @Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar JavaScript para abrir nueva ventana. Por ejemplo, añadimos a tu código un nuevo valor en ViewBag, como ViewBag.Encontrado = true. (puede ser otro valor, como string.Empty)

```
public ActionResult ChAzul(double ? titulo) {
  ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
  var suscriptor = cn.cargarDatos(Convert.ToDouble(titulo));
  var caracteres = Convert.ToString(titulo).Length;
  string uname = string.Empty;
  if (Session["uname"] != null) {
    uname = Convert.ToString(Session["uname"]);
  }
  var usuario = cn.datosCob(uname);
  if (uname == string.Empty) {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  } else if (usuario[0].conectado == false) {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  } else if (caracteres <= 3 || caracteres > 6) {
    ViewBag.Alert = "La cantidad de caracteres no puede ser menor a 4 (cuatro) ni mayor a 6 (seis).";
    return View("Cuotas", usuario);
  } else if (suscriptor.Count <= 0) {
    ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, este título no existe.";
    return View("Cuotas", usuario);
  } else {
    ViewBag.Encontrado = true; // aquí está el valor de control
    // y ahora regresamos al formulario (deberás indicar la vista correcta)
    return View();
  }
}
```

Después, en el archivo cshtml que contiene el formulario incluimos un código JavaScript para abrir la nueva vista en otra ventana. Si existe el valor de ViewBag.Encontrado entonces se ejecutará ese código:

```
@if (ViewBag.Encontrado != null)
{
    <script>
        var miRedirect = document.createElement('a');
        miRedirect.setAttribute('href', '/ChAzul/Index?parametro01=valor01&parametro02=valor02');
        miRedirect.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        miRedirect.click();
    </script>
}
```

El código JavaScript es muy simple: crea un enlace a la ruta ChAzul/Index con 2 parámetros (deberás cambiar el valor del atributo HREF a tus necesidades) y se abrirá en otra pestaña.

Si te preocupa la seguridad, recuerda comprobar en tus acciones si el usuario está logueado y si tiene permisos, etc (tal y como demuestras en tu código).

Comment: Excelente aporte, muchas gracias